# Saving multiple data entries to database with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, postgresql

in my project that I created with django, I duplicate the data entries with the help of a button, but when I want to save them to the database, it always saves the last added data.

models.py

```
class Records(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Ad Soyad',null=True,blank=True)
   date = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)   
   hours = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
   tel = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Telefon Numarası',null=True,blank=True)
   tcNo = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='TC Numarası',null=True,blank=True)
   adress = models.CharField(max_length = 200,verbose_name='Adres/Köy',null=True,blank=True)
   kurum = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Kurum',null=True,blank=True)
   diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Tanı',null=True,blank=True)
   intervention = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Müdahale', null=True,blank=True)
   medications = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='İlaçlar', null=True,blank=True)
   conclusion = models.CharField(max_length = 200,verbose_name='Sonuç',null=True,blank=True)
   doctor = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Doktor',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.Ölçüm',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.Tansiyon',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_pulse = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.Nabız',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_spo2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.SPO2',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_respirations_min = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.Solunum/DK',null=True,blank=True)
   record_one_fire = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='1.Ateş',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.Ölçüm',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.Tansiyon',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_pulse = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.Nabız',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_spo2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.SPO2',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_respirations_min = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.Solunum/DK',null=True,blank=True)
   record_second_fire = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='2.Ateş',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.Ölçüm',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.Tansiyon',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_pulse = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.Nabız',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_spo2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.SPO2',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_fire = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.Ateş',null=True,blank=True)
   record_third_respirations_min = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='3.Solunum/DK',null=True,blank=True)
   medications = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
   scale_used = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
   return self.username
```

forms.py

```
class RecordsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Records
    fields="__all__"
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='redirect')
```

def record_form(request):

```
if request.method == "POST" and 'registrationSave' in request.POST:
    records = Records()
    records.username = request.POST.get('username')
    records.date = request.POST.get('date')
    records.hours = request.POST.get('hours')
    records.tel = request.POST.get('tel')
    records.tcNo = request.POST.get('tcNo')
    records.adress = request.POST.get('adress')
    records.kurum = request.POST.get('kurum')
    records.diagnosis = request.POST.get('diagnosis')
    records.intervention = request.POST.get('intervention')
    # records.medications = request.POST.get('medications')
    records.conclusion = request.POST.get('conclusion')
    records.doctor = request.POST.get('doctor')
    records.record_one_measurement = request.POST.get('record_one_measurement')
    records.record_one_blood_pressure = request.POST.get('record_one_blood_pressure')
    records.record_one_pulse = request.POST.get('record_one_pulse')
    records.record_one_spo2 = request.POST.get('record_one_spo2')
    records.record_one_respirations_min = request.POST.get('record_one_respirations_min')
    records.record_one_fire = request.POST.get('record_one_fire')
    records.record_second_measurement = request.POST.get('record_second_measurement')
    records.record_second_blood_pressure = request.POST.get('record_second_blood_pressure')
    records.record_second_pulse = request.POST.get('record_second_pulse')
    records.record_second_spo2 = request.POST.get('record_second_spo2')
    records.record_second_respirations_min = request.POST.get('record_second_respirations_min')
    records.record_second_fire = request.POST.get('record_second_fire')
    records.record_third_measurement = request.POST.get('record_third_measurement')
    records.record_third_blood_pressure = request.POST.get('record_third_blood_pressure')
    records.record_third_pulse = request.POST.get('record_third_pulse')
    records.record_third_spo2 = request.POST.get('record_third_spo2')
    records.record_third_fire = request.POST.get('record_third_fire')
    records.record_third_respirations_min = request.POST.get('record_third_respirations_min')
    records.medications = request.POST.get('medications[]')
    records.scale_used = request.POST.get('scale_used[]')
    
    
    print(dict(records.medications))
    print(dict(records.scale_used))

    records.save()
    return redirect('/index/tables')
else:
    return render(request,'registration_form.html')
```

registration.html

```
<div class="row" id="InputsWrapper">
                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="record_medications" name="medications" style="height: 100px" placeholder="İlaçlar" required></textarea>  -->
                                            <label for="">İlaç Adı:</label>
                                            <select class="form-select form-select-lg" name="medications[]" id="medications">
                                                <option>Lütfen İlaç Seçiniz</option>
                                                {% if medicationName%}
                                                    {% for medicationName in medicationName %}
                                                        <option value="{{medicationName.medicationName}}">{{medicationName.medicationName}}</option>
                                                    {%endfor%}
                                                {%endif%}
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <label for="scale_used" class="form-label">Kullanılan Ölçek</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="scale_used" name="scale_used[]">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                        </br>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_medications">İlaç Ekle+</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MaxInputs = 20;
    var InputsWrapper =$("#InputsWrapper");
    var AddButton  =$("#add_medications");

    var x = InputsWrapper.length;
    var FieldCount = 1;

    $(AddButton).click(function(e)
    {
        if(x <= MaxInputs)
        {
            FieldCount++;
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="row justify-content-start"><div class="col-4"><label for="">İlaç Adı:</label><select class="form-select form-select-lg" name="medications[]" id="medications_'+FieldCount+'"><option>Lütfen İlaç Seçiniz</option>{% if medicationName%}{% for medicationName in medicationName %}<option value="{{medicationName.medicationName}}">{{medicationName.medicationName}}</option>{%endfor%}{%endif%}</select></div><div class="col-4"><label for="scale_used" class="form-label">Kullanılan Ölçek</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="scale_used_'+FieldCount+'" name="scale_used[]"></div></div>');
            x++;
        }
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

My code is as I mentioned above, after making a selection and entering the scale used entry, I press the add_medications button again, new entries are opened, but when I save it to the database, it saves the last data I entered, not all, how can I solve this?

Comment: please provide full model and full view

Comment: updated problem

Comment: What is meant by the line *when I save it to the database, it saves the last data I entered, not all* ? Also share the full view instead of only POST condition and also urls.py. I think the problem is because of frontend  (I mean JQuery) not Django.